# В админке Битрикс вместо тегов <p> добавляются <span> и <br>

Tags: битрикс24

Если в админке Битрикс при добавлении новости вставлять текст из Word, то теги для верстки не применяются автоматически.

В разделе HTML вместо тегов

добавляются  и 
.

Это особенность админки Битрикс или нужна установка какого-то плагина?

Comment: Когда Вы копируете текст из Word, обычно там уже есть некое форматирование с которым Вы его и копируете, перед вставкой текста следовало бы очищать форматирование.